# select on the basis of some specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a input table in mysql

```
   colA   colB
   ------------
   ABC      -3
   DEF       2
   GHI      -1 
   ABC       4
   DEF      -2 
   GHI      -1
   JKL       2
```

and i want output as

```
   colA   colB
   ------------
   DEF       2
   GHI      -1 
   ABC       4
   DEF      -2 
   GHI      -1
   JKL       2
```

i only want to exclude the negative values for colB for colA = 'ABC' and want to keep rest all the negative and positive values for colA in ('DEF','GHI','JKL')

Answer (score 3):

You may try the following

```sql
SELECT 
    colA,
    colB
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
   NOT (colA = 'ABC' and colB < 0)
```

[View Demo Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ddHNvoA4ciJLEFuRe8RUpg/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT colA, colB
FROM table_name
WHERE colB>=0 OR colA IN ('DEF','GHI','JKL');
```

Second solution

```
SELECT colA, colB
FROM table_name
WHERE colB>=0 OR colA!='ABC';
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do it is by using an OR condition.

```sql
SELECT * FROM input_table WHERE colA <> 'ABC' or colB > 0;
```

This query will return rows where any of the following conditions are true:

- colA is different than "ABC"
- colB is positive

If both conditions are false, it will not return that row.